# NGINX rewrite with Laravel and HHVM

Tags: nginx, laravel, url-rewriting, fastcgi, hhvm

New to nginx and running into some problems with rewrites.

I have a website that is linked to a subdomain test.mydomain.com.
My current nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /test/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.laravel-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/locahost.laravel-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location /admin/ {
        alias /test/public/admin/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;      

    include hhvm.conf;  # The HHVM Magic Here

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Below is the content of the (default) hhvm.conf

```
location ~ \.(hh|php)$ {
    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

I visit test.mydomain.com and everything works perfectly fine.
However! I also have an admin panel on test.mydomain.com/admin. All requests to
`test.mydomain.com/admin/*` should be rewritten to `/test/public/admin/public/*`,
instead with my current configuration they are all rewritten to public/index.

My folder structure looks a bit like this:

```
/test
    /admin
        project.stuff
        /public
            index.php
            etc.php
    /public
        index.php
        etc.php
```

**MAJOR EDIT**

I added the following conditional to my hhvm.conf:

```
if ($request_uri ~* /admin) {
    root /test/admin/public;
}
```

/admin requests now get rewritten accordingly. The nginx docs state that if two location patterns match, only the most simple one will be used (sort-of). All that remains now is getting this to work with not only .hh and .php files but with asset files (js, css, jpg etc) as well.

I thought something similar would suffice but sadly it doesn't:

```
location ~ \.(js|css)$ {
    if ($request_uri ~* /admin) {
        root /test/admin/public;
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try an `alias`? `location /admin/ { alias /test/admin/; }`

Comment: @Deadooshka, nginx docs instead recommend `location /admin/ { root /test; }` - http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias But probable these are equivalents.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### This part applies to the initial edition of the question

`root` directive can be used inside `location {}`, so in your case the configuration might look like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    ...

    location / {
        root /test/public;
        ...
    }

    location /admin/ {
        root /test;
        ...
    }
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#root

**Minor update:**

I have replaced `try_files $uri $uri/ index.php?$query_string;` with `try_files $uri $uri/ =404` as it seems more logical for me, considering `index index.html index.htm index.php` is here.

---

### This part applies to the second major edition of the question

This is correct version of the configuration based on information you provided so far:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name localhost;

    root /test/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    ...

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        ...
    }

    location /admin/ {
        alias /test/public/admin/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
        ...
    }
}
```

However, based on your statement that after you moved `root` into `location`s your regular site stopped working, it can be concluded that you have not provided all needed information, and there is something else wrong in your configuration, that's why I asked you to append to your question your **complete** nginx configuration, it will make life much easier for both of us...

---

### This part applies to the third major edition of the question

This should finally work for you:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /test/public;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name localhost;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/localhost.laravel-access.log;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/locahost.laravel-error.log error;

    charset utf-8;

    location /admin/ {
        alias /test/admin/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /admin/index.php?$query_string;
        include hhvm.conf;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        include hhvm.conf;
    }

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    # Deny .htaccess file access
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

Probably you also need to replace in the `hhvm.conf` file and in the `fastcgi_params` file this line:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

with the following:

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the direction of nginx' root feature. I updated my question based on your answer.

Comment: For some reason, StackOverflow doesn't let me update my answer, so I briefly answer here: - If base directory of your admin panel scripts is actually `/test/public/admin/public` and not `/test/admin` as your initially stated, then you should use `location /admin/ { alias /test/public/admin/public/; }` Please note, end slash in the `alias` path is required and the path should be absolute, not relative. The latter requirement applies to `root` path also!

Comment: Appreciate your edit! I started out by moving the root declaration inside the location / {}, doing this resulted in the webpage not showing at all (404) so there seems to be some kind of difference. I've been tinkering with root/alias all day now and can't find a working combination it's frustrating!

Comment: Can you add the complete listing of your current nginx configuration to the question?

Comment: Updated question, included complete conf file

Comment: The problem is in `include hhvm.conf;`. Can you post contents of `hhvm.conf` file?

Comment: I included the hhvm.conf

Comment: I'm an idiot: I see I made a terrible little mistake in my folder structure, please look at updated question

Comment: I updated the answer. And there is a minor addition.

Comment: I replaced my config with your final version and replaced the line in hhvm.cnf but it's still the same. The 'normal' webpage works, everything with /admin in front of it still gets sent to /test/public/index.php. I can't believe how something that would take a minute in apache is making me tear my hair out in nginx.

Comment: Then you also need to replace in `fastcgi_params` file the line you replaced in the `hhvm.conf`. I have updated my answer accordingly. The modifications from "MAJOR EDIT" section of your question are wrong and not needed.

Comment: You're right, changing the line in both fastcgi_params and hhvm.conf works for both php and all other files thank you ever so much!